# Swift NSDictionary values return nil even after checking values exist inside

Tags: ios, swift, nsdictionary

I am not sure why my NSDictionary values are returning nil even after printing "employeeUserData" after I assign the firebase snapshot to it and seeing that the values are there. When I run my app to test if I can pull the Strings from the NSDictionary it is saying that it is a nil value. I've used this code before and this method has worked, not sure why all of a sudden it's not working and returning nil, and yes this is coding and stuff like this happens all the time lol just trying to understand why this particular problems is happening. Thanks.

```
let employeeUid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
var employeeUserData: NSDictionary?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    Database.database().reference().child("employees").child(employeeUid!).child("Business").observe(DataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in
        print("VALUE CHANGED IN USER_PROFILES")
        self.employeeUserData = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
        //store the key in the users data variable
        self.employeeUserData?.setValue(employeeUid, forKey: "uid")
        print(self.employeeUserData!)
    }) { (error) in
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }

    printUserData()
}


func printUserData() {
    print(self.employeeUserData!["businessuid"] as! String)
}
```

Comment: The first step is to stop using `NSDictionary` in Swift. Use a proper Swift dictionary.

Comment: Besides critiquing my code, can you help with the actually problem?

Comment: Is `"businessuid"` a key in `snapshot.value`?

Comment: yes it actually is, I can give you the printout if you'd like

Comment: @LukasBimba Actually I meant that to be helpful. Things will be simpler when you use the correct data type.

Comment: @rmaddy I understand where you are coming from, yet I find using NSDictionary for firebase calls much easier. I basically only use NSDictionary for my firebase code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you're fetching the data from the database asynchronously (which is the correct way to do it) but you are calling `printUserData` synchronously. Because of that, `printUserData()` gets called before the actual data gets fetched & set.

When you run this code, notice you're seeing the print in `printUserData()` execute before `print(self.employeeUserData)` gets called.

Comment: yes, very true. What would be your recommendation to avoid this? Setting up another "func" or something?

Comment: What are you actually trying to do when you call `printUserData()`? Right now it looks like you're just trying to validate that you have the data, but I'm guessing the next thing you wanted to do was respond to the data you've fetched?

Comment: Yes, I would take the "uid" from there and use in another firebase call to get another users info.

Comment: You should call `self.printUserData()` on the line after `print(self.employeeUserData!)` because the data will have been set to the property at that point